# Pygame - movement inconsistent

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a top-down puzzle game with pygame, and my movement has been wierd. What happens is that when I press a key to move horizontally and a key to move vertically at once, the character will only move if it is touching a horizontal surface. Here is my movement and collision code:

```
def move(self, dx, dy):
    self.dx = dx
    self.dy = dy
    if self.dx != 0:
        self.move_single_axis(self.dx, 0)
    if self.dy != 0:
        self.move_single_axis(0, self.dy)

def move_single_axis(self, dx, dy):
    self.dx = dx
    self.dy = dy
    self.rect.x += self.dx
    self.rect.y += self.dy
    for wall in walls:
        if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
            if self.dx > 0:
                self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
            if self.dx < 0:
                self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
            if self.dy > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
            if self.dy < 0:
                self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom

def checkMovement(self):
    if self.paused == False:
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.move(5, 0)
        elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.move(-5, 0)
        elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.move(0, -5)
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.move(0, 5)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [minimal example that still produces the error and that we can just copy paste and run](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Problem is, my program is very, very, large.

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll get help if you don't provide an mcve. It can be difficult or even impossible to find the errors without a good example. Start from scratch, just add a simple while + event loop, the wall and the player class and the movement code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see following issue:

```
def checkMovement(self):
    if self.paused == False:
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.move(5, 0)
        elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.move(-5, 0)
        if keys[pygame.K_w]: # !!! CHANGE !!!
            self.move(0, -5)
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.move(0, 5)
```

Solves this your problem?

I would also merge the two functions move_single_axis() and move() into one. I can't see why it would make sense to have both.

Weird is in your code how you handle dx and dy. You have a class where your functions are there, so what for do you pass dx, dy to these functions when you have direct access to self.dx self.dy which values you can set before calling this functions?

Why not doing it this way:

```
def checkMovement(self):
    if self.paused == False:
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.dx = 5
        elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.dx = -5
        if keys[pygame.K_w]: 
            self.dy = -5
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.dy = 5
        move()
```

where `move()` is:

```
def move(self):
    self.rect.x += self.dx
    self.rect.y += self.dy
    for wall in walls:
        if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
            if self.dx > 0:
                self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
            if self.dx < 0:
                self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
            if self.dy > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
            if self.dy < 0:
                self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom
```

Comment: There are various problems with this answer. The methods shouldn't be merged, otherwise you'd get incorrect behavior when the player touches a wall and moves in two directions. You first have to move him horizontally and check the collisions, then vertically and check the collisions again, otherwise you don't know with which side the player collided. The next problem is that the player keeps moving once you pressed a button (two `else` clauses would be needed). Changing `elif keys[pygame.K_w]:` to `if keys[pygame.K_w]:` doesn't explain the incorrect behavior that was mentioned in the question.

Comment: Also, wait until the questioner has provided a minimal, complete and verfiable example before you answer. You're just guessing. The code in the question is not complete enough to give a meaningful, correct answer.